# Determine the minimum value of $S=p+q$

Tags: fractions, interval-arithmetic

*question*

For a fixed natural number $ n \geq 1$ we consider all rational numbers of the form $\frac{p}{q}$, with $p,q \in N*$ and $\frac{n - 1}{n  } < \frac{p}{q }< \frac{n}{ n+1}$ Determine the minimum value of the sum $S=p+q$.

*my idea*

Because  $\frac{n - 1}{n  }$ and  $\frac{n}{ n+1}$ are subunitar we get that

$\frac{p}{q} \in (0,1)$

Which means that $0<p<q$

From here i tried to process the initial inequality, but I have not reached anything.

Hope one of you can help me! Thank you!

Comment: What does $~N*~$ represent?

Comment: Superficially, it seems that as $~n~$ increases, the viable choices for the sum $~(p+q)~$ increase.  So, superficially, it seems that you should explore $~n = 1,~$ which (apparently) yields $~(p,q) = (1,3).~$  Outlawing $~n=1,~$ it seems that $~n=2~$ yields $~(p,q) = (7,12).~$  Proving the minimality may be a job for brute force.  However, my instinct is that a brute force answer is not the intent of the problem composer, since otherwise, the problem lacks educational value.  ...see next comment

Comment: To attempt *pseudo-telepathy* against the problem composer, you need to detail (preferably directly in the posted question), what is the source of the problem?  Further, if the problem is from a book or class, what theorems, previously solved problems, or worked examples led up to this (assigned) problem?

Comment: What about the average between $\frac{n-1}{n}$ and $\frac{n}{n+1}$?

Comment: You haven't addressed the issue of theorems, previously solved problems, or worked examples.  Further, it might be helpful if you could give the explicit name of the publication or class name, where the problem was assigned.

Comment: Dominique intends $$\frac{\left( ~n^2 - 1 ~\right) + n^2}{n(n+1)}.$$

Comment: Typo in my previous comment.  Since *average* is requested, the expression needs the $~\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}~$ scalar.  "...how is this going to help..." : Unclear.  That approach has the advantage that the generated fraction must be strictly between the two pertinent fractions.  On the other hand, it is unclear whether the generated fraction can be improved upon.  Consider, for example, setting $~n=2,~$ which implies that you are looking for a fraction between $~\dfrac{6}{12}~$ and $~\dfrac{8}{12}.~$ ...see next comment

Comment: @user2661923 $\frac12<\frac35<\frac 23$

Comment: As the comment of @DanielMathias has just indicated, the generated fraction is not always optimal.  That is, when $~n=2,~$ a better choice is $~(p,q) = (3,5).$  It looks like the only improvement on $~(3,5)~$ is if $~n=1~$ is allowed, which permits $~(p,q) = (1,3).~$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier to subtract everything from $1$ first. So write $\frac rq=1-\frac pq$. Now we need $\frac rq\in(\frac1{n+1},\frac1n)$.

Clearly $r=1$ doesn't work, since it would lead to $n<q<n+1$.

Trying $r=2$, we get $\frac1{n+1}<\frac 2q<\frac 1n$, and we can rearrange to get $2n<q<2n+2$. This has a solution, $q=2n+1$, from which we get $p=q-r=2n-1$ and $p+q=4n$.

Now suppose $r\geq 3$. We need $\frac rq<\frac 1n$, so $q>rn$. Since everything's an integer, we have $q\geq rn+1$. Therefore $p+q=2q-r\geq 2rn+2-r\geq 6n-1>4n$. So the solution we found above minimises $p+q$.

Answer (score 3):

the mediant of  positive fractions is between them. In this case
$$  \frac{2n-1}{2n+1}   $$
with sum $4n \; . \; $

Continued fractions are in many  number theory books. You want a more specific topic called Farey Series. Let me see what references I can give  that discuss mediants.

Good one, Edward Burger, Exploring the Number Jungle: A journey into Diophantine Analysis. Module 2  is Farey Sequences, pages 11-15.

Excellent, Lemma 2.6 on page 13.  Type that in

Lemma 2.6. Let $\frac{p}{q} < \frac{r}{s}$  be two rational numbers with $ps-rq = -1$ Suppose that $\frac{a}{b}$  is a rational number satisfying  $\frac{p}{q} \leq \frac{a}{b} \leq \frac{r}{s}.$  Then there exist nonnegative integers $\lambda, \mu$   such that
$$     a = \lambda p + \mu r \; \; , \; \; \;  b = \lambda q + \mu s      \; \; .  $$

Also in Hardy and Wright,  next Niven and Zuckerman

In Niven and Zuckerman, fifth edition (with Montgomery), they put this fact about Farey sequences, Theorem 6.4 on page 298: given consecutive fractions in a Farey sequence, the mediant is the unique fraction with smallest denominator. I would say this is not immediate for your problem as you need to show your fractions are consecutive  in the ordered list with denominators no larger than $n+1$